# Which god is responsible for smarana in humans?

Tags: gods, goddess

A person may have so much knowledge and the required knowledge has to be remembered at a particular time to accomplish a task. It is called as smarana (getting remembrance).

Which god is responsible for smarana in humans? Is there any mention regarding the same in scriptures?

Comment: I can think of a demon: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apasmara to preserve knowledge he could not be killed.

Comment: Its GarudA for Acquiring vedic knowledge and for retention its hanuman vayu or mukya prana Brahma and saraswati and vedavyasa

Comment: Check taratamya in Davita will give you list of deity and their ruling field and where in your body you need to do upasena

Answer (score 1):

It’s One aspect of Shiva called Vamadeva is responsible for veiling. It’s part of panchanana functions the five-fold functions of Shiva. Hiding knowledge that you have learnt at appropriate times or let it flow to your Jivatma. Of course that is delegated to Shanishwara mostly...it is in almost all Shaiva scriptures.. lookup
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadasiva